# Magento 1.7.0 General error: 1005 Can't create table 'db_name.catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 150)'

Tags: catalog, reindex, flat-catalog

I'm trying to manually reindex my categories via SSH since it doesn't work in the Magento Admin panel.

Here's what I've done and checked so far from suggestions I found on the net:

• Cleared tmp folder
• Cleared var/locks folder
• Deleted catalog_category_flat entry in db (there was no catalog_category_flat_1)
• Server isn't full - there's 2gb of hosting space left
• User has all access rights for the database
• Used ssh to reindex (php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat)

When I try to reindex via ssh, this is the error I get:

```
/home/mysitehere/public_html/shell$ php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
Category Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'db_name.catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 150)' in /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#6 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2039): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#7 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(604): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#8 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1418): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#9 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1431): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTables()
#10 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(246): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#12 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/mysitehere/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/mysitehere/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'db_name.catalog_category_flat_store_1' (errno: 150)' in /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#4 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /home/mysitehere/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2039): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#6 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(604): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#7 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1418): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#8 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php(1431): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTables()
#9 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Indexer/Flat.php(246): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#10 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /home/mysitehere/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/mysitehere/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/mysitehere/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Server details:

Apache version  2.2.26
PHP version     5.3.27
MySQL version   5.5.36-cll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

The tables were MyISAM instead of InnoDB.

http://www.fortwaynewebdevelopment.com/magento-general-error-1005-cant-create-table-fixworkaround/

Answer (score 0):

The table is not created because that error 150 MySQL occurs:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,398982,399084#msg-399084

I dumped the foreign constraint key on this table from a Magento database:

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_flat_1`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
       (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Both columns `entity_id` in both tables should be the same:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085001/mysql-creating-table-with-fk-error-errno-150 .
You either modified column `entity_id` on table `catalog_product_entity` or Magento doesn't generate the table using DDL statements correctly.

Comment: Hi, I followed your instructions and got the following error in phpmyadmin: "Can't create table 'testwebsite_db.#sql-68f_29076b' (errno: 121)". Any ideas?